# regex works very slow

Tags: c++, regex, qt, visual-studio-2015

I have lots of files less than 64 kb and I need to convert them with code below.

Here is working code in QT with `QRegExp`.

I tried to rewrite it in MSVC with `regex_replace` and faced with the problem of very slow work.

## QT:

```
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(=)[ ]{0,}"), QString("="));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(==)[ ]{0,}"), QString("=="));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(>)[ ]{0,}"), QString(">"));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(<)[ ]{0,}"), QString("<"));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(\\&\\&)[ ]{0,}"), QString("&&"));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(\\|\\|)[ ]{0,}"), QString("||"));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(\\})[ ]{0,}"), QString("}"));
temp.replace(QRegExp("[ ]{0,}(\\{)[ ]{0,}"), QString("{"));
```

## MSVC:

```
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(=)[ ]{0,}"), "=");
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(==)[ ]{0,}"), "==");
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(>)[ ]{0,}"), ">");
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(<)[ ]{0,}"),"<" );
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(\\&\\&)[ ]{0,}"),"&&" );
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(\\|\\|)[ ]{0,}"),"||" );
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(\\})[ ]{0,}"), "}");
temp = regex_replace(temp, std::regex("[ ]{0,}(\\{)[ ]{0,}"),"{" );
```

For example: `std::string` temp(size of ~18kb) processed for about 10 sec for every line.

What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: Which are the performance using `Qt` instead? I mean, is one of them far better than the other? It is not clear from what you wrote.

Comment: Have you tried a simple regexp to check if the time is consumed by the regexp automaton or by reading the files in some unlucky fashion?

Comment: @skypjack I cant tell the exact execution time in QT but It was so quick that i did not have to think about it.

Comment: @mcw Files were already open and regexp worked with std::string `(for (auto it = stringList.begin(); it != stringList.end(); ++it)
 {
  auto temp = *it;)`

Comment: If you are using Qt > 5.0 try to use QRegularExpression instead and see how that compares to QRegExp: _The QRegularExpression class introduced in Qt 5 is a big improvement upon QRegExp, in terms of APIs offered, supported pattern syntax and speed of execution._
Any reason why you are moving away from a Qt based implementation?

Comment: Ty for imformation about The QRegularExpression class. Next time i will use it instead of QRegExp.

Comment: I have the same problem - msvc 2015 implementation of std::regex_replace is very slow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::regex` implementations available aren't really up to snatch (yet?), but `boost::regex` is reasonably fast.

Comment: It looks like boost library has solution on each problem faster and more elegant than std.

Comment: Well, ``boost::regex`` was first. But I wonder why the clang/libc++ people didn't base their ``std::regex`` on ``boost::regex``. It performs better and has a permissive license. Which means there is no excuse to perform worse.